# How to filter for a specific key's value in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, filtering

We have json value that returns an array:

```
  "sentMoney": [
                {
                    "amount": 3840.83,
                    "currency": "MXN",
                    "isMajor": false
                },
                {
                    "amount": 200,
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "isMajor": true
                }
            ]
```

What I'm trying to do is filter it so I can get the value for the "amount" key. This is what I have so far but I get a " has no subscript members" error message:

```
 let filteredItem = self.postTransferSuccess?.sentMoney.filter{$0["sentMoney"]}[0]
                    self.emailMessage.amount = filteredItem
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: create a `Transaction` type ie class or struct. Let it have 3 properties, `amount`, `currency` and `isMajor`. Then sort based on its `amount` property, otherwise you would have a long line of conversions, similar to Lamar's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is.
`.filter` isn't the right function here though bc `.filter` is used to remove unwanted elements of an array/collection. (so you filter with a condition and it'll copy over the value to a new collection only if that condition evaluates to true).

What you might be looking for is `.map`.

As in:

```
let amountsOnlyArray = sentMoney.map({ $0["amount"] })
```

which would give you `[3840.43, 200]`

If you only want the first item for some reason and want to ignore I ***THINK*** you should be able to do

```
let firstAmountOnly = sentMoney[0]["amount"]
```

Note that `amountsOnlyArray` is actually of type `[Any]` so you'll have to do some casting somewhere.

Note this assumes you have some sort of `sentMoney:[String:Any]` collection which I'm assuming given your initial code filters `sentMoney`

Answer (score 1):

Since your `sentMoney` is key that has an `array of dictionary` has value, you should do this:

```
 let resultObj =  (dict["sentMoney"] as? [[String:Any]])?.filter({ ($0["amount"] as? Double) == someValue }).first // dict should be the name of your dictionary
```

keep in mind your data should like what is below, so no curly braces:

```
var dict = ["sentMoney": [
   ["amount": 3840.83,"currency": "MXN", "isMajor": false],
   ["amount": 200.0,"currency": "USD","isMajor": true]
  ]
]
```

Your second option is to transform your dictionaries into structs, which will become easier to iterate over.

```
struct Item {
    let amount:Double
    let currency:String
    let isMajor:Bool


    init?(_ dict:[String:Any]?) { //<-- failable init will return a nil if there an empty key
    guard let _dict = dict,
    let amount = _dict["amount"] as? Double,
    let currency = _dict["currency"] as? String,
    let isMajor = _dict["isMajor"] as? Bool
        else { return nil }

    self.amount = amount
    self.currency = currency
    self.isMajor = isMajor
   }

}
```

Now when you need to iterate, you'll do:
 var someValue = 200.0

```
 if let arr = dict["sentMoney"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        let items = arr.flatMap({ Item($0)}) //<-- will remove any optional item from your list
        let singleItem = items.first { $0.amount == someValue } 
     // or arr.flatMap({ Item($0) }).filter({ $0.amount == someValue}).first
  }
```

**(Side Node)** Avoid using `!` at all cost, use either if let or guard statement to unwrapped your optionals.

Comment: this code is pretty insecure because it uses force unwrapping

Comment: I had it a side note :) @Gabox

Comment: `filter({ $0.amount == someValue}).first` would unnecessarily iterate the whole array. You should use `first(where:{ ... })` method instead

Comment: Change `as! Double` to `as? Double ?? 0`, `as! String` to `as? String ?? ""`, `as! Bool` to  `as? Bool ?? false` and `as! [[String:Any]]` to `as? [[String:Any]] ?? []`

Comment: @LeoDabus I was on a rush that's i did provide that solution, but now I made the necessary changes :)

Comment: @Lamar `[String:Any]?` not necessary you dont want to pass nil to the initializer. Change it to `init?(dict: [String:Any])` and remove `let _dict = dict` and use plain dict inside your initializer